# How use XMLReaderFactory now? because this is deprecated

Tags: java, xmlreader, java-10

I'm trying use XMLReaderFactory, but this is deprecated. 
Now, how Can I create a instance of XMLReader?

Answer (score 25):

The [documentation for `XMLReaderFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/XMLReaderFactory.html) recommends [`SAXParserFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html)

```
SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
```

Comment: @Igor If this post answers your question, please consider to mark the answer as "accepted". Kindly refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Somehow this new XMLReader doesn't work with the same code as before. Maybe that's why it's not accepted. I'm reverting to the deprecated factory.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLReader xmlReader = org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newXMLReader();` Creates a new SAX XMLReader, with sensible defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here as we just make a big jump from Jdk8 to jdk17, for compatibility here is my code from my own factory:

```
XMLReader saxReader;
try {
    SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader saxReader  = parser.getXMLReader();           
    saxReader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
} catch (javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException parseEx) {
    throw new SAXException(parseEx);
}
```

making the parser ns aware solved the compatibility issue link to the usage of a DefaultHandler.
The XXE protection was already there (see: [owasp XXE](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)) but worth mentioning anyway I think.
the try catch wrapping is due to the fact that a new exception is now thrown (you can remove this part and manage exception somewhere else if you can)